# Cannot post a new story in instagram with `user_tags` in python

Tags: python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, instagram-graph-api

Having issue in posting a new instagram story using **graph API**

```
userTags = [{'username': 'testing', 'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.2}] 
instaObj = { 'access_token' : accessToken, 'video_url': reelsUrl, 'user_tags': userTags}
res = requests.post(instaPost, instaObj)
```

Getting the below error

```
'message': '(#100) Param user_tags[0] must be a JSON object.'
```

Tried json dumps. still the same error

i tried to dump the `userTags` using json.dumps(userTags)

Still facing the same error

it's expecting a json for user_tags.

Comment: `requests.post(instaPost, instaObj)` - how does this know it is supposed to send JSON? Does this not need the `json =` part, as shown here, https://scrapeops.io/python-web-scraping-playbook/python-requests-post-requests/#post-json-data-using-python-requests ?

Comment: Tried by adding the `json=instaObj`. Still ending up with the same error

Comment: Have you tried deserializing the userTags string to a JSON dictionary ? Try json.loads(userTags).